# Is it possible to configure routes in a container (empty/non-routing parent)?

Tags: model-view-controller, routes, zend-framework2

I'm creating an authentication module to deal with the login/logout of users into the website.

I want to keep the paths simple:

- https://example.com/login
- https://example.com/logout

But, for some functions within the application/module, it would make sense to me to set up the two routes under some kind of parent:

```
'routes' => array(
    'auth' => array(
        'type'    => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '',
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'login' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/login',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'Base\Controller\Authentication',
                        'action'        => 'login',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ),
            'logout' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/logout',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'Base\Controller\Authentication',
                        'action'        => 'logout',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

The problem is - without any route in the parent, I can't get a match on either of the child routes (`/login` and `/logout` return 404 with routing errors).

If I do put a route in the parent, like `/auth` then the urls only match as `/auth/login` and `/auth/logout`.

I don't want the parent to interfere with routing in other modules - for example, the "home" route at `'/'` is already defined in a different module and I don't want to replace or modify that.

About the only thing I have found on the internet similar to what I'm trying is a [resolved bug report from 2012](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-442).

Is there a way to define a non-routing parent that can hold routable children in ZF2 configuration?

Comment: maybe using the `Part` router (http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-part) could be an option

Comment: Not sure how that helps - the documentation makes it look just like a way to create the part of the tree that's in the config already - can you provide an example in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`'routes' => array(
    'auth' => array(
        'type'    => 'Literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/',
        ),
        'may_terminate' => true,
        'child_routes' => array(
            'login' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'login',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'Base\Controller\Authentication',
                        'action'        => 'login',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ),
            'logout' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'logout',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller'    => 'Base\Controller\Authentication',
                        'action'        => 'logout',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
            ),
        ),
    ),`

Comment: The home route `'/'` is defined in a different module, and I don't want to override it from this auth module...